# winRT 8.1 crash report

Tags: windows-runtime, event-log, windows-8.1

I'm developing a metro UI app using winRT 8.1 and I need to implement a crash report. Customer wants to check on launch if app was crashed last time and sent a report via email if so. As I know system event logs are not available for winrt. Application will be sideloaded(probably Airwatch).
What options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send emails without user interaction. So you probably want to send the crash report to a web service.

If you don't want to create this solution on your own, use [bugsense](/questions/tagged/bugsense) or other [instrumentation](/questions/tagged/instrumentation) services; some of them come for free.

If you want to do it by yourself: in your App.xaml.cs file find the UnhandledException handler, (1) save the exception info somewhere, then (2) try to send this information to the web service and finally (3) remove the info from whereever you saved it in (1). 
Obviously you also need a web server running the web service which you also have to create.

Comment: I've used UnhandledException. Seems like it works for me, thanks.